# Jupyter seems to take false python version

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Up to 2 hours ago I had a working setup with Jupyter, Python3, Pandas and Mathplotlib.

I installed jupyter_contrib_nbextensions and enabled some of the extensions. Afterwards the first visible problem was that pandas wasn't found anymore (ImportError: No module named pandas).

If I start a python3 session in a terminal, I can import pandas without problems.

The notebook shows that the Python 3 kernel is running. I tried to verify that by executing

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

This shows

> sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=15, releaselevel='candidate', serial=1)

Seems like Python 2 kernel, what would explain why pandas is not found. 
I tried to change the kernel, switched between the installed python 2 and python 3 kernel using the jupyter web UI, but it always returned the python 2 version and never was able to import pandas, but it always displayed python 3:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a correct way to verify which kernel is running, I never tried it before.

I removed all the extensions, but up to now I could not get it running again.

What can I do to get a running python 3 kernel back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved. Or at least got an working instance again, but without knowing what really went wrong.
Removed jupyter, manually cleaned up any left-over files, reinstalled it. Now it is working properly again.