# ModuleNotFoundError after upgrade

Tags: python, upgrade, python-3.12

I used to work with python version 3.9 in Jupyter lab.
When I tried to install skrub, an extension of sk-learn, it appeared that I needed a version greater than 3.10. So, I installed the lastest python version, i.e 3.12.

Once in Jupyter, I checked the version using `! python --version`. It confirmed I was in Python 3.12.2. All fine.

Then, I installed skrub also from Jupyter using `!pip install skrub`.
Again, all went fine, and I got confirmations that skrub, scikit-learn, numpy, scipy, pandas, ... were successfully installed in folder c:\users\JCF\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages

All fine, no error or warning.

Now, in the same notebook, practically on the next cell, I enter the command
`from skrub import TableVectorizer`.
I then get a message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skrub'

Based on other questions asked here, I understand that this is related to windows paths. Now, it's more about the next step.
What would be the recommended approach from this point to get a fully working version in 3.12? Should I completely remove version 3.9?

**Note:**
Using the magic command (as recommended by Wayne), I get the same message before upgrading from version 3.9. The messages I get are the following:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.1.0 Requires-Python >=3.10

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement skrub (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for skrub
```

Comment: The reason for getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skrub'` in practically the next call is likely because you are not installing were the kernel environment backing your running Jupyter `.ipynb` file is running because you are using outdated approaches. In 2019, the magic install commands were added. Unlike running an install with the exclamation point inside a running notebook, the magic install commands insure the installation occurs where the kernel is running. Specifically, in your case the command should be `%pip install skrub`.

Comment: <continued> See more about the modern magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

Comment: The trick does not help.   
I tried using the magic command, but I get the exact same message when I was in version 3.9: 
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.1.0 Requires-Python >=3.10  
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement skrub (from versions: none)  
ERROR: No matching distribution found for skrub

Comment: You said you were using 3.12. I quote: "It confirmed I was in Python 3.12.2." " I installed the lastest python version, i.e 3.12.". You cannot use 3.9. The PyPI page for skrub clearly states: "**Requires: Python >=3.10**". Please address the problem and not a downstream symptom. For example your title is a result of not addressing the issue. `! python --version` is not reflecting the kernel that Jupyter is using. The exclamation point means it runs off in a temporary shell instance which may not be where Jupyter is running. It is a similar issue as I described for the magic install command.

Comment: <continued> I wonder if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52360659/8508004) will give you what Jupyter is using? So you know before you try to fix since you got mislead by exclamation point. Also maybe [here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-know-which-python-is-running-in-your-jupyter-notebook/) to see if it matches your situation better. For then fixing it,  there are lots of posts already targeting your underlying issue that you need to work on: ...

Comment: <continued>  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67064443/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719599/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35561198/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37857536/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52102289/8508004). By the way, a lot of these are old and so you won't have `python2` or `python3` commands, just `python`, I think. And hopefully you'll also note that when you want to be switching Python versions going forward, you should be using Anaconda or virtual environments that makes managing things easier.

Comment: <continued> For example, if you a project that relied on you having Python 3.9, you may have created all sorts of headaches for yourself by changing things to 3.12. That project would potentially stop working on your system. And so that is not ideal if you had invested a lot of time. Even if you are starting out, it is worth the time to make things like what you face now easier to sort out by using something like the Anaconda Distribution & investing the time up front to see what they suggest about getting started & using the tool properly to change Python versions & associations with Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was an internal mix related to the paths of the two versions.
I finally uninstalled version 9 completely. Then, as I was one version late for Jupyter lab, I decided to upgrade Jupyter right after. All went nicely and everything is working fine with the new versions.

Finally, the approach I feared the most was the easiest and most straightforward. All the scripts I wrote using former versions of python, pandas, sk-learn work nicely.